# Magento Analytics - Detect CategoryId & ProductId?

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.7.0.2, google-analytics

I have a custom tracking script which is recording things like Product and Category Page views. Because the script loads on every page, not all pages are category pages and would have a $categoryid OR a Product_View with a $productid.

**What would be the best way to detect if $categoryid OR $productid exist in order to pass those values to the tracking script?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block you use to call the script use some logic after calling:

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category'); //if null then not a category
$category->getParentId(); //if null $catagory is a top level category
$product  = Mage::registry('current_product'); //if null then not a product
$product  = Mage::registry('product'); //if null then not a product
```

For more info check out: [Magento: How to tell if you're on a category page, or product page in .phtml file(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503842/magento-how-to-tell-if-youre-on-a-category-page-or-product-page-in-phtml-fil)

Comment: This works very well. Can I assume in my situation `Mage::registry('current_product');` and `Mage::registry('product');' would be checking for the same thing?

Comment: Yes. They are the same thing, but I have read some people have issues with caching and `Mage::registry('current_product');`